# Second order generics in Dart

Tags: dart

Can you have second order generics in Dart?

```
abstract class Foo<T, ContainerType<T>> {}

class FooList<T> extends Foo<T, List<T>> {}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and some more characters to make it 30

Comment: :) 12 more to go

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like:

```dart
abstract class Foo<T, C extends Iterable<T>> {}

class FooList<T> extends Foo<T, List<T>> {}
```

(If not, try refining the question and say what you want to achieve).

Comment: Trying to solve this issue: https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/351